Finding irreducible representations of $D_{2n}$ using Mackey little group method
Let $D_{2n}$ be the dihedral group on 2n elements, consisting of n rotations and n reflections. I know the group of n rotations form a normal subgroup of $D_{2n}$ and $D_{2n}$ is a semidirect product of $C_2$ and $C_n$, $C_n$ being the normal subgroup here. How do I find irreducible representations of $D_{2n}$ using Mackey's little group method? I already know that I'm meant to get two orbits when I act on the set of characters of $C_{n}$, but how does the induced representation bit work? Appreciate any help I can get.

Isn't this just all about induction of represantions from subgroups?

Yeah, I want the intuition behind using Mackey's little group.
